# How can I identify the foreground 'app' in OS?

Tags: android, monitoring

I am an Android developer and I want to write an if statement in my application. In this statement I want to check which app is run which time in my mobile like Facebook, messenger,You Tube,chrome etc when its open and when its close. How can I do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with the *if statement* part but I guess that what you are looking for is [UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html).

Take into account that this API requires the permission `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`, which is a system-level permission and will not be granted to third-party apps. However, declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user of the device can grant permission through the Settings application.